# LUA : Scene not being created. What is wrong?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, transition

I'm building a game where I have a start screen and clicking the start button it should take me to the FIRST level. Some stuff happens and then I will be taken to the SECOND level.

However I'm running into problems and can't seem to find a solution.
When I click the start button it seems to get stuck in the create function because i prints out something. I was told you don't have to place anything in the create function and just put everything in the SHOW FUNCTION. Was i mislead?

START SCENE

```
local composer = require("composer")
local widget = require("widget")

local options = {effect = "fade", time = 800}
local startBtn;

local function start(event)
    -- load first scene
    composer.gotoScene( "level1", options);
    startBtn:removeSelf();
    print("Start Game")
end

startBtn = widget.newButton(
    {
    left = 75,
    top = 100,
    id = "startBtn",
    label = "Start",
    onEvent = start
    }
)
```

When I click the START button it should take me to the FIRST LEVEL which is here
and is where i'm running into problems.

```
local composer = require( "composer" );
local scene = composer.newScene();
local widget = require ("widget");

function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view;

end

function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase
    local params = event.params;
    print(params);

    if (phase == "will") then
        print("Will")
    elseif (phase == "did") then
        print("Did")
        local bg = display.newImage ("bg.png",  
        display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY);


        ------- ALEX KIDD  ---------------------------------
        local options =
        {
            frames = {
                { x = 1, y = 2, width = 16, height = 25}, --frame 1       
                { x = 18, y = 2, width = 16, height = 25}, --frame 2        
                { x = 35, y = 2, width = 16, height = 25}, --frame 3        
                { x = 52, y = 2, width = 16, height = 25}, --frame 4
                { x = 1, y = 54, width = 16, height = 24},  --ready1
                { x = 19, y = 54, width = 16, height = 24}, --ready2
                { x = 37, y = 54, width = 29, height = 24}, -- rock
                { x = 67, y = 54, width = 33, height = 24}, -- scissor
                { x = 101, y = 54, width = 33, height = 24},  -- paper       
            }
        };
        local sheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "kidd.png", options );


        -- Create animation sequence for animation
        local seqData = {
            {name = "normal", start=1 , count = 4, time = 800},
            {name = "faster", frames={1,2,3,4}, time = 400},
            {name = "shake", frames={5,6}, time = 500},
            {name = "rock", frames={7}},
            {name = "paper", frames={9}},
            {name = "scissor", frames={8}},

        }
        local alex = display.newSprite (sheet, seqData);
        alex.x = display.contentCenterX-100;
        alex.y = display.contentCenterY+83;

        alex.anchorX = 1;
        alex.anchorY = 1;



        ---------- JANKEN ---------------------------------
        local jankenOpt =
        {
            frames = {
                {x= 154, y= 13, width= 39, height= 48 }, -- shake1
                {x= 195, y= 13, width= 39, height= 48 }, -- shake2
                {x= 236, y= 13, width= 32, height= 48 }, -- set
                {x= 270, y= 13, width= 16, height= 48 }, --r/p/s
                {x= 287, y= 13, width= 16, height= 48 }, --r/p/s
                {x= 305, y= 13, width= 15, height= 48 }, --r/p/s
                {x= 69, y= 13, width= 41, height= 48 }, --flap1
                {x= 110, y= 13, width= 40, height= 48 }, --flap2
            }
        };
        local jankenSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "chars.png", jankenOpt );

        -- Create animation sequence janken
        local seqDataJanken = {
            {name = "flap", frames={7,8}, time = 500},
            {name = "shake", frames={1,2}, time = 500},    
            {name = "set", frames={3}, time = 10, loopCount=1},        
        }

        local janken = display.newSprite (jankenSheet, seqDataJanken);

        janken.x = display.contentCenterX+100;
        janken.y = display.contentCenterY+83;

        janken.anchorX = 1;
        janken.anchorY = 1;


        -------------- button setup
        local btnOpt =
        {
            frames = {
                { x = 3, y = 2, width=70, height = 22}, --frame 1       
                { x = 78, y = 2, width=70, height = 22}, --frame 2        
            }
        };

        local buttonSheet = graphics.newImageSheet( "button.png", btnOpt );

        local function foo (wow) 
            alex:play();        
            janken:play();
        end

        local function bar (wow)
            alex:pause();    
            janken:pause();    
            --alex:setFrame(2);     --keep it at this frame 

            -- NEXT: generate more buttons
        end

        -- Function to handle button event
        local function go( event )
            -- event.target is the button widget
            print (event.phase, event.target.id)

            transition.to(alex, {time=2000, x=170, onStart = foo, onComplete = bar})
        end

        local btnGo = widget.newButton(
            {
                x = 200,
                y = 20,    
                id = "btnGo",
                label = "Go!",
                labelColor = { default={ 0, 0, 0 }, over={ 0, 0, 0 } },    
                sheet = buttonSheet,
                defaultFrame = 1,
                overFrame = 2,
                onPress = go,
            }
        );

        -------------- play buttons

        local function shoot (buttonID) 

            local randomHand = math.random(4,6);
            -- position Janken and draw his hands
            janken:setSequence("set"); 
            hand = display.newImage (jankenSheet, randomHand, display.contentCenterX+61, display.contentCenterY+60);

            if (buttonID == "btnRock") then
                alex:setSequence("rock");  -- just show rock for now
            elseif (buttonID == "btnScissor") then  
                alex:setSequence("scissor");  -- just show rock for now
            else
                alex:setSequence("paper");  -- just show rock for now
            end
        end


        local function play (event)
            if (event.phase == "ended") then
                alex:setSequence ("shake");
                alex:play();

                janken:setSequence("shake");
                janken:play(); 


                local t = timer.performWithDelay (1500, function() shoot(event.target.id) end, 1);


                print (event.target.id);   -- which button was it?
            end
        end


        local btnRock = widget.newButton(
            {
                x = 80,
                y = 20,    
                id = "btnRock",
                label = "Rock",
                labelColor = { default={ 0, 0, 0 }, over={ 0, 0, 0 } },    
                sheet = buttonSheet,
                defaultFrame = 1,
                overFrame = 2,
                onEvent = play,
            }
        );

        local btnPaper = widget.newButton(
            {
                x = 80,
                y = 50,    
                id = "btnPaper",
                label = "Paper",
                labelColor = { default={ 0, 0, 0 }, over={ 0, 0, 0 } },    
                sheet = buttonSheet,
                defaultFrame = 1,
                overFrame = 2,
                onEvent = play,
            }
        );

        local btnScissor = widget.newButton(
            {
                x = 80,
                y = 80,    
                id = "btnScissor",
                label = "Scissor",
                labelColor = { default={ 0, 0, 0 }, over={ 0, 0, 0 } },    
                sheet = buttonSheet,
                defaultFrame = 1,
                overFrame = 2,
                onEvent = play,
            }
        );

        local scoreAlex = display.newText ( {text="Alex: 0", x=230, y=60, fontSize=20});

        scoreAlex:setFillColor (0,0,0);
        scoreAlex.anchorX = 1;

    end

end

function scene:hide( event )
    local sceneGroup = self.view

    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        transition.cancel(enemy);
    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then

    end

end


scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enter", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )

return scene
```

Comment: and don't you think it would be useful to know what is printed out after you get stuck in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are adding a listener `scene:addEventListener( "enter", scene )` which should be `scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )` (Change enter to show)

Your listener is not even being fired, because it was not added with the correct name.

Composer uses the following events: [create, destroy, show, hide](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/scene/index.html).